# css not getting applied for velocity template in Liferay Theme

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, velocity, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I am using LIferay Theme to create a theme for a website.
IN the portal_normal.vm file, I have included all the html code and css I have defined in custom.css

THe problem is that css from custom.css is not getting applied to portal_normal.vm page

SHould I include some file in velocity file which tells that custom.css should be included?

Also is it ok to include all css code in velocity?

Regards

EDIT:

custom.css and portal_normal.vm are inside _diffs folder

Comment: Did you try by removing .sasscache folder from your deployed theme  and restart server?

Comment: @LuckyBoy :
Thaks for the reply. There is no .sasscache folder in the theme project. Can you point me to the location of that folder? I searched but there is no folder by that name.

Comment: tomcat/webapps/your-theme/css/.sass-cache. If you are using tomcat bundle

Comment: @LuckyBoy: There is no folder or any file in it. I checked. Yes I am using tomcat bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the custom.css under `~/theme/docroot/_diffs/css/custom.css`

see the main.css in `~/theme/docroot/css/main.css` it should include

```
...
@import url(custom.css);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work may be problem in browser cache.. try to run ant clean and then run ant deploy.

and also try to copy portal_normal.vm file to _diff/templates directory.

_diff/templates/portal_noraml.vm and change here.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My files are under _diffs folder. And I haave cleant n deployed it many times but css is not getting applied in any way